# confused about file owner in linux

Tags: linux, shell

```
---x--x--- 1 root stapusr    87992 Oct 20 23:44 staprun
```

What I showed above is the owner of file `staprun`. But user `root` doesn't belong to group`stapusr`.  What does it mean?

I assumed that before `chown userxxx:groupxxx filename` has been executed, the `userxxx` should belong to `groupxxx` .

Comment: Root is unfettered by such trivial details as 'does the user belong to the group'.  At the o/s level, there is no such enforcement.

Answer (score 6):

Of the user and group that owns a file, the user is not necessarily a member of the group.

Comment: Of course, only root (I'm pretty sure) can chown a file's group to something the user's not in.

Comment: That's normally, but not necessarily, the case. It might be that the directory sets the group permission (SGID bit), while the user has write permission to the directory (perhaps public write permission, perish the thought, unless the directory has the sticky bit set; or perhaps because of ACLs).  But in the normal case, a file is created belonging to the effective GID of the process that creates the file.